# Filter for just User objects in specific OU

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I am writing a powershell script to rename users within a specific target OU.

The script runs fine, however I have noticed that the script also attempts to rename anything contained within child OUs as well. This is not the behaviour I am after but I am not sure how I change the filter to be specific to this requirement.

This is the top part of the script.

```
Import-Module ActiveDirectory

# Change the following Target OU to match your target
$ou = "ou=Testing,ou=My Users,dc=my,dc=domain"

# Set up Log files
$users = $null
New-Item -ItemType Directory -Force -Path C:\Logs

$Logfile = "C:\Logs\$($ou).log"
Out-File -FilePath $Logfile -Force -encoding ASCII

Function LogWrite
{
  Param ([string]$logstring)
  Add-content $Logfile -value $logstring
  Write-Host $logstring
}

# Start processing

$users = Get-ADUser -SearchBase $ou -Filter * -Properties *
ForEach($user in $users) 
......
```

I believe the `-Filter` parameter needs something more but I am not sure what, I assume I need to specify the objects as users only. Any help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have already specified users only by using `Get-ADUser` (users only) and not `Get-ADObject` (all objects). You need to specify `-SearchScope OneLevel` for `Get-ADUser`. The default value is `Subtree` (all child OUs)

> PS > **Get-Help Get-ADUser -Parameter searchscope**
>
> -SearchScope 
>       Specifies the scope of an Active Directory search. Possible values for this parameter are:
>         Base or 0
>         OneLevel or 1
>         Subtree or 2
>
> A Base query searches only the current path or object. **A OneLevel
>   query searches the immediate children of that path or object.** A
>   Subtree query searches the current path or object and all children of
>   that path or object.
>
> The following example shows how to set this parameter to a subtree
>   search.   -SearchScope Subtree
>
> The following lists the acceptable values for this parameter:
>
> Base
>
> OneLevel
>
> Subtree
>
> Required?                    false
>
> Position?                    named
>
> Default value                **Subtree**
>
> Accept pipeline input?       false
>
> Accept wildcard characters?  false

Comment: Thank you for a great answer Frode I have updated my script with that and it works perfectly.